# how do save new obj within has set primay in magento2?

Tags: magento2

in magento2 when i save new obj $data = [name=>2, label=>new]; when save i call

$mode->setData($data);
$model->save();

how do save new same with $data = [id => "1" name=>2, label=>new];

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do this on a model that is mapped on a table with an autoincrement primary key.
The actual insert is done in `Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb::saveNewObject()` that looks like this:

```
protected function saveNewObject(\Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel $object)
{
    $bind = $this->_prepareDataForSave($object);
    if ($this->_isPkAutoIncrement) {
        unset($bind[$this->getIdFieldName()]);
    }
    $this->getConnection()->insert($this->getMainTable(), $bind);

    if ($this->_isPkAutoIncrement) {
        $object->setId($this->getConnection()->lastInsertId($this->getMainTable()));
    }

    if ($this->_useIsObjectNew) {
        $object->isObjectNew(false);
    }
}
```

this means that if `$this->_isPkAutoIncrement` return `true` then the id is reset and is auto generated.

You can try to add this in your resource model associated to the model and see if it works.

```
protected $_isPkAutoIncrement = false;
```

but I don't know what impact it will have on the other cases where you use  your model.